# Downloading image from Dropbox using sync api Android

Tags: android, api, download, synchronization, dropbox

I'm trying to download an image from Dropbox that I've uploaded and save it to my device. I'm using the Android sync api and I don't know how to go about doing this. I'm able to get the path of the file that was uploaded to Dropbox using DbxPath. How can I then save this image to my device?

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the path, just open the file ([`DbxFileSystem.open`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileSystem.open)) and read out the content. (If you want to copy it to a local file, I'd suggest calling `getReadStream` on the file and then copying data from that stream into the local file you've created.)

Comment: I've been messing with my code and it seems my path isn't right. I have my files in the path /Apps/Image Upload Test/. I create a DbxPath like; DbxPath path = new DbxPath(new DbxPath("Apps"), "Image Upload Test/" + _dbxFileName); I check to see if the file exists and it keeps returning file not found. I look in my Dropbox and see that _dbxFileName is the name of the file I want to download from Dropbox. Any ideas on what could be wrong with the way I'm using DbxPath?

Comment: The root of the `DbxPath` is your app folder, so if your app is called `Image Upload Test`, then your app folder will appear in a user's Dropbox at `Dropbox/Apps/Image Upload Test`, but when you use it in a `DbxPath`, it should just be `/`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to locate my files.